# Determine which templates are used by which views/ URLs in django

Tags: django, templates, url, django-views

I have a fairly large django project consisting of several individual apps. I am farming out some of the front-end work (CSS, HTML tweaks) to people who aren't over-familiar with django. To that end I'd like to generate a list of templates for each URL pattern any given engineer is working on. This will save much time that would otherwise be spent manually tracking down the templates used during a view's render phase.

For example, if Bob is working on URLs beginning with `/accounts/` then I'd like to generate a list of all the templates used by any view that handles requests to those URLs.

My initial thought is to use something in the test framework since that has access to the templates rendered during a request. However, I can't guarantee that all URLs or views will be exercised (sadly I don't have 100% test coverage), and a missed template is unlikely to be noticed. I don't mind writing a set of tests that simply exercise each view, but don't want to duplicate existing efforts. Also certain views require POSTed data or authentication to function correctly - although I suspect that's an issue I'll have to face no matter what approach is used.

Are there any utilities or snippets that will do what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[django-debug-toolbar](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) is a must for developing with Django, It includes a [panel detailing all templates used during a request](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/panels.html#template).

I've found the SQL panel is the most helpful for improving page load times as it details slow and duplicate queries.

It can slow down requests when enabled, disabling all panels but those that you use helps.

Comment: This works! I'd hoped for something command-line based but this will do. Thanks!